How to fix wifi drivers
Not really sure fix is the right word but I recently had a hdd that windows couldn't recognize and decided to swap to Linux for a fix and it worked, now I'm debating fully swapping to Ubuntu but cannot use wireless wi-fi there just isn't an option, I have a motherboard with wifi and Bluetooth built in, b550-plus wifi is the motherboard and the bios is tuf gaming, everything else in Ubuntu seems to work just no wifi drivers I take it and I cannot find any does anyone got a possible solution

Hello thank you for the advice however that person mentions the use of an Intel ax200 which as far as I understand I do not have I am using the built in wifi from my motherboard

Welcome to Ask. The following links to your motherboard https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/tuf-gaming/tuf-gaming-b550-plus-wifi-ii/ which suggests wifi meets '802.11ax' standard.  The following answer (2nd) suggest commands to find out the drive (if any) ubuntu is using for your device. My last link seem to suggest how to debug a '802.11ax' device on a linux (ubuntu) rig. https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Configuring-WiFi6-as-AP-in-linux-with-hostapd/m-p/1223560 You should try and append to your question more details as you acquire them

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos for the next steps you should take.
